# How to get the distance from the bottom of the screen to the top of the document?

Tags: javascript

Probably it has been answered many times but I haven't managed to find it.

How to know the position of the bottom of the screen from the top of the document when you scroll it?

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
    console.log("The distance from the bottom of the screen to the top of the document");
});
```

I would like to know the vanilla JS option please. Many thanks.

Comment: const body = document.body;
const html = document.documentElement;
const height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight,
  html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
console.log(height)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you need:

```js
document.write('<div>1</div>'.repeat(200))

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  console.log(document.documentElement.offsetHeight - innerHeight - pageYOffset)
})
```